# Wordpress splits up words in email body

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send email with one long line as a body. Sending

```
$msg = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ac eros vitae felis posuere auctor nec ut metus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Integer nulla turpis, iaculis vitae massa vel, ultricies tempus libero. Praesent mi magna, elementum in sollicitudin sed, blandit non turpis. Phasellus ultrices, enim ac rhoncus hendrerit, nulla ante vehicula turpis, nec vehicula libero libero eget diam. Mauris et dolor sem. Aliquam egestas, nisi a pulvinar vehicula, nisi lorem eleifend enim, in egestas enim dolor quis nibh. Nulla ultricies rhoncus mi, id accumsan est bibendum ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut purus felis, bibendum vel ornare fringilla, bibendum nec metus. Nulla sollicitudin viverra arcu, et elementum lectus tristique vel. Sed et nulla faucibus, egestas libero vulputate, sagittis nulla. Morbi porttitor fermentum tincidunt. Morbi eros tortor, efficitur vitae nibh a, molestie mollis nisl. Nulla dictum velit e get finibus pulvinar. Sed non dolor ut est interdum placerat'
```

Receiving

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Mauris ac eros vitae felis posuere auctor nec ut
metus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Integer
nulla turpis, iaculis vitae massa vel, ultricies tempus
libero. Praesent mi magna, elementum in sollicitudin
sed, blandit non turpis. Phasellus ultrices, enim ac
rhoncus hendrerit, nulla ante vehicula turpis, nec
vehicula libero libero eget diam. Mauris et dolor sem.
Aliquam egestas, nisi a pulvinar vehicula, nisi lorem
eleifend enim, in egestas enim dolor quis nibh. Nulla
ultricies rhoncus mi, id accumsan est bibendum ac. In
hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut purus felis, bibendum
vel ornare fringilla, bibendum nec metus. Nulla
sollicitudin viverra arcu, et elementum lectus
tristique vel. Sed et nulla faucibus, egestas libero
vulputate, sagittis nulla. Morbi porttitor fermentum
tincidunt. Morbi eros tortor, efficitur vitae nibh a,
molestie mollis nisl. Nulla dictum velit e get finibus
pulvinar. Sed non dolor ut est interdum placerat
```

I havn't found anything about line splitting in wp_mail sources, however it uses PHPMailer and for PHPMailer i've found this

https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/issues/detail?id=17

However i have this issue both for SMTP and sendmail.

**UPD: Seems like the problem is not WP itself, but about `Amazon SES DKIM Mailer` plugin using old version of PHPMailer.**

Comment: Did you try setting the encoding like it says in the link? `$vMailer->Encoding="base64";`

Comment: Ye, sure. It doesn't work

Comment: then it most likely has something to do with your email provider. gmaila and many others hard-wrap the lines in plaintext emails. https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/gmail-plain-text

Comment: No, i've tried to do the same with plain mail and it works fine. The bug is in PHPMailer.

Comment: Oh, you're NOT using plaintext? that's your problem right there. Your BROWSER wraps HTML automatically. Nothing you can do about that except maybe try using the `<pre>` tag in your HTML.

Comment: Try using quoted-printable encoding. That will mean that the wrapping is left to the client. PHPMailer doesn't support `format: flowed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just in case if somebody has the same issue. It was fixed in this commit

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/commit/a3c729eca33b3cc3e1d4b3b5187e4890d99ad470

So i've just manually updated WP core to the last PHPMailer. But this didn't helped. After this i just forced it to use 'quoted-printable' if not 'base64' and it works.